# Scheduling a custom mesos executor with Airbnb Chronos REST API

Tags: distributed-computing, job-scheduling, mesos

The [Chronos site](http://nerds.airbnb.com/introducing-chronos/) mentions that Chronos supports custom [Mesos](http://incubator.apache.org/mesos/) executors.
The Mesos examples show how to write a custom Mesos executor (master/src/examples/java/TestExecutor.java). However, I am unable to find any documentation about how to go about scheduling such a custom executor via the Chronos RET API.
Any help or pointers about this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Florian's answer work for you?

Answer (score 7):

We wrote a sample executor without any logic. You can find it here: 
https://github.com/mesosphere/sample_mesos_executor.

Here is an example of how you post to a custom executor. Please note that the executor has to be executable. We use [`arx`](https://github.com/solidsnack/arx) in this example, which is a executable tar file. You could also point to a shell script that does a `java -cp foo.jar my.executor.implementation arg1 arg2...`.

```
echo '{"schedule":"R/2012-11-10T00:52:00Z/PT90M", \
  "name":"request_event_counter_hourly", \
  "command":"/srv/mesos/utils/run_emr.sh jar eventcounter.RequestEventCounter", \
  "epsilon":"PT15M", \
  "executor":"/srv/mesos/utils/async-executor.arx" }' | \
  http POST your-chronos-host.com:4400/scheduler/iso8601
```

Comment: How would you start a job from the Chronos REST API using that sample Mesos executor? The Chronos docs only give examples for running tasks with the default command executor.

Comment: This is the Executor class being extended: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mesos/mesos/0.9.0-incubating/org/apache/mesos/Executor.java